# How find focused Control in MVVM?

Tags: mvvm

I want to control focus from my ViewModel.  How can I locate the currently focused control in my View, and how can I set focus on another control from my ViewModel?

Comment: That's not MVVM.  Handle it in the codebehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving a control focus really should be done in the code behind, not in the ViewModel.  Your ViewModel is specifically used for communicating between your View and you Model.  Any UI changes that don't have to do with you Model can be done in the code behind.